# MonoTouch: SQLite-net thread safety and SQLiteConfig.Serialized

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make **SQLite** default to be "more" thread-safe by calling something like this code:

```
SqliteConnection.SetConfig (SQLiteConfig.Serialized);
```

I think it's related to setting:

```
 DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1
```

But how to do that is a mystery too.

Using the Awesome **SQLite-NET ORM** for MonoTouch, there doesn't seem to be a way to set SQLiteConfig.Serialized?

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (not really recent) copy of `SQLite.cs` has this method defined in `SQLite3` type:

```
public static extern Result Config (ConfigOption option);
```

and `ConfigOption` is defined as:

```
public enum ConfigOption : int
{
    SingleThread = 1,
    MultiThread = 2,
    Serialized = 3
}
```