# Threading issues with SQLite3 and C# async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, sqlite

I am trying to save some data to a SQLite3 database. If I do not use async, I can save the data without any problems. As soon as I try to use the following code however, I receive the following error:

`{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`

From my UI, I invoke the following SyncDomainTablesAsync method:

```
private readonly IDataCoordinator _coordinator;

public Configuration(IDataCoordinator coordinator)
{
    _coordinator = coordinator;
}

public async Task<int> SyncDomainTablesAsync(IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken ct, DateTime? lastDateSynced=null, string tableName = null)
{
    //Determine the different type of sync calls
    // 1) Force Resync (Drop/Create Tables and Insert)
    // 2) Auto Update 

    var domainTable = await GetDomainTablesAsync(progress,ct,lastDateSynced, tableName);
    var items = domainTable.Items;

    int processCount = await Task.Run<int>( async () =>
    {
        int p = 0;
        progress.Report(String.Format("Syncing Configurations..."));

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            progress.Report(String.Format("Syncing {0} Information",item.Key));
            var task = await SyncTableAsync(item.Value); // INVOKED BELOW
            if (task) progress.Report(String.Format("Sync'd {0} {1} records", item.Value.Count,item.Key));
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) goto Cancelled;
            p += item.Value.Count;
        }

        Cancelled:
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {   
            //Update Last Sync'd Records
            progress.Report(String.Format("Canceling Configuration Sync..."));
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        else
            progress.Report(String.Format("Syncing Configurations Compleleted"));
        return p;
    },ct);
    return processCount;
}

private async Task<bool> SyncTableAsync(IEnumerable<object> items, bool includeRelationships = false) 
{
    try
    {
        //TODO: Replace with SaveObjects method
        var i = await Task.Run(() => _coordinator.SaveObjects(items, includeRelationships));
        if (i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The UI invokes the `SyncDomainTablesAsync` method. I then create a new Task and loop through the items that were returned from the `GetDomainTablesAsync` method. During each iteration I  await until the `SyncTableAsync` method completes. Within the `SyncTableAsync` I am calling a SaveObject method inside of a class that implements my IDataCoordinator interface.

```
public override int SaveObjects(IEnumerable<object> items, Type underlyingType, bool saveRelationships = true)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Can not save collection of objects. The collection is null.");
    else if (items.Count() == 0)
        return 0;

    // Check if table exists.
    foreach (var item in items)
        this.CreateTable(item.GetType(), saveRelationships);

    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(this.StorageContainerPath))
    {
        connection.BeginTransaction();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            result += ProcessSave(item, saveRelationships, connection);
        }

        try
        {
            connection.Commit();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            connection.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public override int CreateTable(Type type, bool createRelationalTables = false)
{
    if (this.TableExists(type) == 1)
        return 1;

    using (SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(this.StorageContainerPath))
    {
        try
        {

            // Check if the Table attribute is used to specify a table name not matching that of the Type.Name property.
            // If so, we generate a Sql Statement and create the table based on the attribute name.
            //if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(TableAttribute)))
            //{
            //    TableAttribute attribute = type.GetAttribute<TableAttribute>();
                // Strongly typed to SQLiteCoordinator just to get a SqlQuery instance. The CreateCommand method will create a table based on 'type'
                var query = new SqlQuery<SQLiteCoordinator>().CreateCommand(DataProviderTypes.Sqlite3, type);
                query = query.TrimEnd(';') + ";";

                cn.Execute(query);


            //}
            // Otherwise create the table using the Type.
            //else
            //{
            //    cn.CreateTable(type);
            //}

            // If we are to create relationship tables, we cascade through all relationship properties
            // and create tables for them as well.
            if (createRelationalTables)
            {
                this.CreateCascadingTables(type, cn);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The flow of the code goes

UI->SyncDomainTablesAsync->SyncTableAsync->SaveObjects->SaveTable(type)

The issue that I have is within Save Table. If I just use SaveTable synchronously I have no issues. Using it in my async method above, causes a thread abort exception. The exception is thrown within the SQLite.cs file included with SQLite.net (within the . The weird thing is that the table is created in the database, even though the exception is thrown. The error is thrown some times when the Prepare() function is called and the rest of the time when the SQLite3.Step() function is called.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery ()
{
    if (_conn.Trace) {
        Debug.WriteLine ("Executing: " + this);
    }

    var r = SQLite3.Result.OK;
    var stmt = Prepare (); // THROWS THE ERRROR
        r = SQLite3.Step(stmt); // THROWS THE ERRROR
    Finalize(stmt);
    if (r == SQLite3.Result.Done) {
        int rowsAffected = SQLite3.Changes (_conn.Handle);
        return rowsAffected;
    } else if (r == SQLite3.Result.Error) {
        string msg = SQLite3.GetErrmsg (_conn.Handle);
        throw SQLiteException.New (r, msg);
    } else {
        throw SQLiteException.New (r, r.ToString ());
    }
}
```

I assume that because my foreach statement awaits the return of `SyncTableAsync` that none of the threads are closed. I am also getting a `system transaction critical exception` that says "attempting to access a unloaded app domain".

Am I using await/async incorrectly with Sqlite3 or is this an issue with Sqlite3 that I am not aware of.

Attached is a photo of the Parallel's stack and the exception.

[image]

**EDIT**

When I try to run the code above as well in unit tests, the unit tests process never dies. I have to exit Visual Studio in order to get the process to die. I am assuming something in SQLite.dll is grabbing a hold of the process when the exception is thrown and not letting go, but I am not sure.

**EDIT 2**

I can modify the initial method `SyncDomainTablesAsync` to the following and the code runs without error. The issue is my use of async and await I believe.

```
    public async Task<int> SyncDomainTablesAsync(IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken ct, DateTime? lastDateSynced=null, string tableName = null)
    {
        var domainTable = await GetDomainTablesAsync(progress,ct,lastDateSynced, tableName);
        var items = domainTable.Items;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            _coordinator.SaveObjects(item.Value, typeof(object), true);
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoTouch: SQLite-net thread safety and SQLiteConfig.Serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436741/monotouch-sqlite-net-thread-safety-and-sqliteconfig-serialized)

Comment: I actually tried that prior to posting, but it didn't fix the issue. I don't believe I am accessing the database across multiple threads (at least not that I am aware of, unless I did my await's incorrectly), the connection to the database is never shared between threads.